# Adding new components with default layout

Tags: core-ui

I have just downloaded the angular admin template. Then i add a new component:

```
ng g n test
```

When I navigate to the component, the default layout is not applied. I guess it uses the app.component layout. How do you tell the component it should use the default UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add a new componet follow these steps:

1. create a component-name-routing.module.ts file
2. create a component-name.module.ts file
3. create a component-name.component.html file
4. create a component-name.component.ts file

**component-name.component.ts file**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-componentName',
    templateUrl: './component-name.component.html',
})

export class NameComponent implements OnInit {}
```

**component-name-routing.module.ts file**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { NameComponent } from "./component-name.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: NameComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'route title'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: ''
      },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class ComponentNameRoutingModule {}
```

**component-name.module.ts file**

```
// Angular
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

// Theme Routing
import { ComponentNameRoutingModule } from "./component-name-routing.module";

import { ComponentNameComponent } from "./component-name.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ComponentNameRoutingModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        ComponentNameComponent
    ]
 })
 export class ComponentNameModule {
     constructor() {}

 }
```

all this in a new folder in the **views** directory and you'll be good to go.