# Add new component view with CoreUI 2.1 Angular

Tags: angular, core-ui

I followed this SO post: 
[Adding new components with default layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843931/adding-new-components-with-default-layout/54778405#54778405)

but can't get the dashboard to show the new component. I'm using the current CoreUI 2 release from GitHub. Am I supposed to update the nav and route as well? If so, could I get an example? Hacking at this doesn't seem to work, and the documentation is very lacking.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

Just Create the new component using the below commands

ng generate component YOUR_COMPONENT_NAME

shortcut

ng g c YOUR_COMPONENT_NAME

Then it will create a component folder in your app directory.

Make sure you have imported in app module and declared in declarations array.

then put router-outlet in app.module.html

After that put your view code i.e html code in your app.YOUR_COMPONENT_NAME.html and style in app.YOUR_COMPONENT_NAME.css

for more info

https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components